# Can I bring a suitcase aboard the riverboat Koln-Dusseldorfer (K-D) Line, traveling from St. Goare to Mainz, Germany?

Tags: luggage, germany, riverboats

I want to experience traveling up the Rhine River in Germany but do not want to do a reverse trip in order to get my luggage. Can I take my luggage aboard The Koln-Dusseldorfer (K-D) Line?

Answer (score 3):

According to their [FAQ](https://www.k-d.com/en/faq/) (see "Bicycles & Luggage"):

> There is no luggage office on board or at the wharf, therefore large baggage cannot be transported (max. hand baggage size). The passenger is responsible for transporting their luggage and other items brought on board to and from the ship. The carrier accepts no liability for luggage and other items brought on board.

However, the german version is muss less specific, saying:

> Eine separate Gepäckaufbewahrung ist weder an Bord noch an der Anlegestelle vorhanden, daher sollte kein großes Gepäck (bis max. Handgepäckgröße) mitgeführt werden. Für die Beförderung des Gepäcks und der an Bord gebrachten Gegenstände zum/vom Schiff hat der Fahrgast selbst zu sorgen. Eine Haftung für Gepäck oder an Bord gebrachte Gegenstände wird ausgeschlossen.

with the relevant part saying that no large baggage *should* be brought aboard. So *maybe* you can take it with you, but I wouldn't bet on it.

If you want to be sure, you should write to them at info@k-d.com.

Note however, that if they don't allow it, a train trip back will be much shorter than going by boat.

Comment: I think _less restrictive_ is a better way to describe the difference than _less specific_. It is very specific in German. It means _we don't have a place for you to store the luggage and then walk around on the boat. You always have to keep your huge suitcase with you, which is probably inconvenient. And if someone steals your stuff, bad luck. So we suggest you don't bring luggage, but we don't really care._

Comment: +1, so wonderful to see some expertise on Father Rhine; I do hope you will continue here.  And for me "sollte" is used as a modal in keeping with the formal tone of the advisory, sietzen, and hence relentlessly ambiguous. Thanks again for a great answer.

Comment: @simbabque I guess you're right, but I guess I'm also right. Note the english version is easy to understand for the traveler, because it just means that you have to leave large bags somewhere else, but the german version could mean a.) bring it and we will transport it, but you have to take care of it yourself, or b.) we cannot guarantee that there is enough space, because there might be many passengers.
This, of course, doesn't really help the passenger, so they better ask beforehand to have a definitive answer.

Comment: @GayotFow: Thanks, I'll try. I agree with you. If it was strict in any way, there would be a better way to phrase it in a formal tone (and I hope, they'd have chosen it then).